# Qt Takes too long to parse a JSON File

Tags: json, qt

I use the following function to parse JSON files.

```
void LoadJSONFileToVariantMap(const QString &filename, QString *error, QVariantMap *result){

    QElapsedTimer timer;

    *error = "";
    QFile file(filename);

    qDebug() << "Start";
    timer.start();

    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)){
        *error = "Could not open file '" + filename + "' for reading";
        return; // QVariantMap();
    }

    QByteArray data;
    data.reserve(50000000);

    //QTextStream reader(&file);
    //QString json = reader.readAll();
    data = file.readAll();
    //QString json(data);
    file.close();


    qDebug() << "Read the data in " << timer.elapsed();

    QJsonParseError json_error;
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data,&json_error);
    if (doc.isNull()){
        *error = "Error parsing the JSON string of the study description: " + json_error.errorString();
        return;// QVariantMap();
    }


    qDebug() << "Interpreted the data in " << timer.elapsed();

    *result = doc.object().toVariantMap();

}
```

I need to return a QVariantMap as that is what I use in app.

To test the code I use this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString input = "my_large_file.json";
    QString error = "";
    QElapsedTimer timer;


    qDebug() << "Loading" << input;
    timer.start();
    QVariantMap map;
    LoadJSONFileToVariantMap(input,&error,&map);
    qDebug() << "Done. Took " << timer.elapsed() << "ms. Error: " << error;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I was wondering, am I doing anything wrong here?. Because loading a 57 MB json file this function takes 16 seconds which seems too long.

I'm using Qt 6.2 by the way. MSVC2019. In case that helps

Comment: How long is it supposed to take?

Comment: To what "loading" are you referring to? What is the timing of data loading and data processing? And the time required for `toVariantMap()`? What is the structure of the json file and how complex is it? A +50MB json file might be quite demanding, especially if its structure has multiple nested levels. We need more details about the situation, for what we know, much of the loading time could be caused by slow data access.

Comment: The 16 seconds also seems to include the reading of the data, not just the parsing.

Comment: Yes. To all of your questions. The data has multiple nested levels, the time reuqired for variant map is aobut 4 seconds and the time for actual data loading is about 220 ms.

Comment: @aarelovich Sorry but I didn't ask any yes/no question. I suggest you to update your post, provide at least one or two cases for the debug output, and a basic example of the data structure, including the container types, possible layer depth and average element count for each container. In any case, I don't know about performance of QJsonDocument for large datasets, but, while much larger sizes are possible and actually used, a +50MB file isn't your typical JSON size. The file size alone is certainly not an indicator of the complexity (and, thus, possible time required to evaluate its »

Comment: @aarelovich » contents), since it may even be a short list of base64 encoded images; nonetheless, it could even be an extremely complex tree structure, only having bool as keys and terminal values, which could affect parsing and time. I know that there are various JSON libraries, with some of them mostly oriented to performance for large/complex datasets. Knowing Qt ideals, which aims balance between capabilities, usability and performance, I'd say it could be understandable that a complex structure would take so much time to load.